# Can you install a Safari extension from within a Mac application?

Tags: cocoa, macos, safari

I was wondering how I could go about installing a Safari extension via a Mac application I build.

Does anyone who's familiar with the Mac SDK know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest something like

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"path/to/myextension.safariextz" withApplication:@"Safari"];
```

Comment: Thanks omz, sounds like that should work.  I wonder if there's a way to install a safari extension via the command line.

Comment: That line of code omz gave works both in GUI app and command line app.

Comment: And for a command line that you can enter, as opposed to something to do in a command-line tool that you write, you can use the equivalent of the answer's code: `open -a Safari path/to/myextension.safariextz`